# Enviar Variables php a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

tengo un problema muy tonto ...

necesito que por medio de un window.location me mande unas variables que estan encriptadas en php.Cuando miro la URL me muestra una cosa horrible, no me manda las variables

**Variables**

```
<?php $usuario= base64_decode($_REQUEST['usuario']) ?>
<?php $IdUser= base64_decode($_REQUEST['IdUser']) ?>
```

**Boton Quien me manda al js**

`<button class="btn btn-outline-info" name="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>" id="guardar" onclick="Borrar();"><span class="fa fa-save"></span>Borrar</button>`

**JS**

```
  var fila =document.getElementById('guardar').name;
  var IdUser = "<?php echo $IdUser? >";
  var usuario = "<?php echo $usuario ?>";
  var tipoUsuario = "<?php echo $tipoUsuario ?>";
   Swal.fire({
    title: 'Desea Eliminar este registro?',
    text: "Si Elimina este registro no volvera a recuperarlo",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Borrar',

  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success',
        )      
        window.location ="../Logica/Eliminar.php?borrar=" + fila + "&tipoUsuario="+ tipoUsuario +"&usuario="+ usuario +"&IdUser="+IdUser; 

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás mostrando un solo usuario o es un listado de usuarios?

Comment: Depronto puede ser un problema de conceptos, pero `base64` no es una función para encriptar, es una funcion para codificar (pero cualquiera que vea el dato lo puede decodificar). Según entiendo lo que necesitas es mandar los datos codificados en base64 desde JS para que el php las pueda decodificar de nuevo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUCION**

la verdad era muy facil de responder ajajajaj

primero se tiene que crear la variable en js llamando un echo de php asi:

**HTML**

```
<script> 
    var usuario="<?php echo $usuario;?>";
    var tipoUsuario="<?php echo $tipoUsuario;?>";
    var IdUser="<?php echo $IdUser;?>";
</script>
```

luego en el js simplemente compilar las variables asi:

**JS**

```
window.location ="../Logica/Eliminar.php?borrar=" + fila + "&tipoUsuario="+ tipoUsuario + "&IdUser=" + IdUser + "&usuario="+ usuario;
```

Answer (score -1):

Mi solucion facilista seria pasar estos datos a unos input con display:none

`<input type="text" id="iduser" style="display:none" value="<?php echo $IdUser ?>" >`

y luego leer los input con jquery o javascript

```
var idusuario= (#iduser).val();
```

Comment: no bro :/ la consola de me dice

Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#tipoUsuario' must be declared in an enclosing class

Comment: Un par de apuntes si me permites... 1) En lugar de display:none yo pondria type="hidden", pero 2) El OP (original poster) quiere mandarlos por GET mediante un window.location, tal como reza el segundo párrafo de su pregunta y eso forzará su visualización si o si